# Limiting access to objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a particular model and that model has finegrained access settings. Something like:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    access = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

Groups consist of particular tags, and those tags are linked to users. Long story short, one way or another the documents are only accessible by particular users. It is very important that this check does not slip through the cracks. So I can see a number of options. One is that every time I access a Document, I add the check:

> Document.objects.filter(access__group__tag__user=request.user)

But there are two drawbacks: a) I query the documents model > 100 times in my views so I will have a LOT of repeated code, and b) it's quite likely that someone will at some point forget to add this restriction in, leaving documents exposed.

So I am thinking that overwriting the objects() makes most sense, through a custom manager. That way I don't duplicate code and I don't risk forgetting to do this.

```
class HasAccessManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(access__group__tag__user=request.user)

class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    access = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    objects = HasAccessManager()
```

However, the problem becomes that request is not accessible there:

> name 'request' is not defined

How to solve this? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: You can not use a `request` in a manager, since, it is not even said that there is a request at all when you do the query. Furthermore it will probably not help much, since some Django code uses the `._base_manager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mixin that your views inherit from. This will prevent having duplicated code everywhere. You'll want to write unit tests to make sure your views are locked down appropriately.

```
class HasAccessMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        # you can still leverage a custom model manager here if you want
        # qs = qs.custom_method(access__group__tag__user=self.request.user)

        qs = queryset.filter(access__group__tag__user=self.request.user)
        return qs

class SomeListView(HasAccessMixin, ListView):
    ...

class SomeDetailView(HasAccessMixin, DetailView):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not yet familiar with mixins so a few questions to clarify. 1) I don't use class views -- will this still work? And 2) in this example it seems like the same queryset is always returned. However, the specific query I do is always different. So I would need a way to have full flexibility and be able to make a variety of queries, but apply a default set of filters to them. Would that still be possible with mixins?

Comment: The mixin will not work for function-based views. The mixin approach would allow you to make a variety of queries. Because querysets can be chained, in your class-based views you'd be guaranteed that the user would at the very minimum only be allowed to access the rows returned from the mixin. If you want to further filter the queryset, the starting point would be what is returned from the mixin.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll look into this. If you have any idea how to make things work for function-based views please do be sure to post as well. Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion for function-based views would be to leverage the custom model manager and make sure unit tests have you covered that people aren't able to access data they shouldn't be.